# Django RestFramework: Token auth errors returning HTTP response instead of JSON

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF backend with a Vue frontend.  It has been working for a while (alpha test), but I am trying to thoroughly test the authentication of the site.

I login as a test user, then go directly to the database and delete that user from the authtoken_token table.  I then hit a backend endpoint to see what error I get.

I'm getting an `AuthenticationFailed` message, but it is an HTTP response, not JSON.  Also, it is a "500 Internal Server Error" instead of a 401 or 403.

Looking at the `handle_exception()` method (rest_framework/views.py), I see that it is checking for `NotAuthenticated` and `AuthenticationFailed` exceptions, so it should match the actual exception of `AuthenticationFailed`.

```py
    def handle_exception(self, exc):
        """
        Handle any exception that occurs, by returning an appropriate response,
        or re-raising the error.
        """
        if isinstance(exc, (exceptions.NotAuthenticated,
                            exceptions.AuthenticationFailed)):
            # WWW-Authenticate header for 401 responses, else coerce to 403
            auth_header = self.get_authenticate_header(self.request)

            if auth_header:
                exc.auth_header = auth_header
            else:
                exc.status_code = status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN

        exception_handler = self.get_exception_handler()

        context = self.get_exception_handler_context()
        response = exception_handler(exc, context)

        if response is None:
            self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

        response.exception = True
        return response
```

How to ensure I get a JSON response?

Comment: What does your view look like?
Using the built in Response() with DRF should generally return the correct response depending on what exceptions were raised.
On a side note, I personally run some of my larger projects with Vue frontends with Djoser authentication. I think it's the most complete auth backend thus far.

Comment: My views are returning correct responses, when the user is authenticated.  Testing with an invalid token, though, is all handled by Django/DRF code - it never actually gets to my view code.  That auth process, being part of DRF, is beyond my control, unless I override, which I don't want to do, for obvious reasons.  I just don't understand why it's not returning "Invalid token" as a JSON response.